# MySQL #1422 Explicit or implecit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Tags: mysql, mariadb, eventtrigger

I try to automate the copy-row from a collection-table to a dedicated table. 
Sometimes the dedicated table does not exist, therefor I check for existance, and if needed I create the table before copying the row.
This code is included in a trigger in MariaDB

From the latest inserted row in the table "allwelds" I want to know the content of the column ProjectName, the complete row have to be inserted in the table with the name of the ProjectName 
First I check the existance of the table.
If the table does not exist (select returns  0 ), I create the table with the name of the variable "qname" and insert the complete row in it.
If the table exist (select returns  1 ) do the insert of the row in the table with the name of the variable "qname"

The following code results in the following error:
MySQL #1422  Explicit or implecit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger

```
BEGIN
DECLARE qname Varchar(24) DEFAULT "EMPTY";
DECLARE qid INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE table_exist INT DEFAULT 5;           

SELECT id, ProjectName INTO qid, qname FROM allwelds WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM allwelds );

SELECT count(*) into table_exist FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA = 'ugm') AND (TABLE_NAME = qname );
CASE table_exist

WHEN 0 THEN
    CREATE TABLE qname ( id int, Datum date, Tijd time, ProjectName Varchar(24), ...........etc, etc, ....................... ); 
    INSERT INTO qname ( id, Datum, Tijd, ProjectName, , ...........etc, etc, ....................... )
        SELECT id, date(timestamp), time(timestamp), , ...........etc, etc, ....................... );   FROM `allwelds` WHERE id = qid;

WHEN 1 THEN 
    INSERT INTO qname ( id, Datum, Tijd, ProjectName, , ...........etc, etc, ....................... )
    SELECT id, date(timestamp), time(timestamp), , ...........etc, etc, ....................... );   FROM `allwelds` WHERE id = qid;

END CASE;
END
```

Can anyone help me with this code?

Comment: Creating a table involves an implicit commit... you cant create a table from a trigger

Comment: Your first sentence is showing the actual problem - in SQL, you don't check if table exists - you assume it does. If it doesn't exist, you get an error that you don't recover from by creating a table from within the database. I understand that you're after the least amount of hassle possible, but dynamic table creation is not the answer. It's not maintainable, it contains magic and it's probably a nightmare to debug. Your problem goes away if you simply assume that table exists. If it doesn't - your system requires some sort of migration script that will create the table upon first run.

Answer (score 1):

There is another problem waiting to be discovered.  `qname` is dynamic, yet you have `INSERT INTO qname ...`, which is using "qname" as a static table name.  The obvious solution is `CONCAT`, `PREPARE`, `EXECUTE`, etc.  But, let's not go that way.

Do not create lots of tables with the same schema.  This is almost always a bad design and a maintenance nightmare, and sometimes a performance problem.

Instead, have an extra column in a *single* table for throwing the stuff into.  And put `qname` in that column.  Probably the first part of the composite `PRIMARY KEY` for that table would be `qname`.

Another problem... Don't discover the columns via a `SELECT` and `MAX(id)`.  Instead, use the pseudo table `OLD` (there is also `NEW`).  It is a lot simpler and faster.  Plus it avoids race conditions where `MAX(id)` could grab the id from a different connection !

Bottom line:  Take the time to study `TRIGGERs` and look at examples.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comments. I realize now that this was a "quick and dirty" way of working. Please can you explain some more around the last comment. I do not understand you statement about the pseudo table

Comment: "Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger." -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html  Read the rest of that page.